# Portable installation of TexLive and dehypht-x-2018-03-31.tex

Tags: texlive, texlive-2019

This question is about a borderline installation of TexLive, and as such it could be off-topic. I am sorry if this is the case.

**Background:** I am trying to install a portable version of TexLive 2019 on a system where I do not have root access. Importantly, there is already a TexLive distribution (located at `/usr/local64.hg/app/teTeX/current`).

**What I did:** I installed TexLive 2019, in portable mode, to some directory in my home. However, near the end of the installation, I see that the variable `TEXMFVAR` points to the wrong place: `TEXMFVAR=/usr/local64.hg/app/teTeX/current/texmf-var`. Ok, let's ignore this. When I try to compile some file with pdflatex, I get

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
---! /usr/local64.hg/app/teTeX/current/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt made by different executable version
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

Trying to create pdflatex.fmt for the new installation, if I run

```
fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex
```

it fails and gives

```
[blah blah]
===========================================
Local configuration file hyphen.cfg used
===========================================
([myhome]/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/hyphen.cfg
([myhome]/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
([myhome]/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex)
([myhome]/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/dumyhyph.tex)
([myhome]/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/zerohyph.tex)
! I can't find file `dehypht-x-2018-03-31.tex'.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.172   \repeat

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
[blah blah]
```

What could I try to do?

Comment: Why are you even in portable mode? All texlive needs is a folder with write access. Afterwards add the texlive path to your path. This is what I do with all my installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no file in my new installation tree contained references to the older installation, I was puzzled by the fact that `pdflatex` was stubbornly using the format file `pdflatex.fmt` from the older installation (even after changing the `PATH` variable of course).

The solution was easy, and I'm wondering why I didn't check this before.
For some reason, there was an environment variable `TEXMFVAR` pointing to the older installation. Unsetting this with the command

`unset TEXMFVAR`

solved the problem.